# In google colab for R, how to install crimedata package?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I usually have no issues with installing packages in google colab for R, but I can't figure out how to fix the issues I'm having (non zero exit status).

```
install.packages("crimedata")
```

outputs

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependencies ‘s2’, ‘units’, ‘sf’


Warning message in install.packages("crimedata"):
“installation of package ‘s2’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("crimedata"):
“installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status”
 Warning message in install.packages("crimedata"):
“installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("crimedata"):
```

and so on...

when I try to import it from github, the same issue happens:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("mpjashby/crimedata")
```

outputs

```
Warning message in install.packages("devtools"):
“installation of package ‘textshaping’ had non-zero exit status”
```

and so on.

alternatively... if anyone would be able to point me to anywhere online where I can find all the data in this package in a CSV, that would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this at the beginning.

```
system("sudo apt install libudunits2-dev")
```

Then install the `crimedata` package.

```
install.packages("crimedata", verbose=T, keep_outputs=T)
```

The `verbose` and `keep_outputs` create detailed output that is invaluable for debugging and which is stored in the `/content` folder. Ignore these options if you don't need the details.